# Android application is not responding while extracting zip file

Tags: android, delphi, zip

I want to extract large zip file via FMX Android app, but Android sees the app is not responding and suggests killing it.

Here my code:

```
procedure AddSoundRes(SfileN: string);
begin
  if trim(SfileN) = '' then ShowMessage('Please Select A File')
  else
    begin
      try
        FormMessage.Show;
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        Archive2 := TZipFile.Create;
        Archive2.Open(SfileN, zmRead);
        Archive2.ExtractZipFile(SfileN, soundpath);
        ShowMessage('Resource added successfully');
      finally
        Archive2.Free;
        FormMessage.Hide;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

How to solve it?

Comment: See [Application isn't responding - Delphi XE6 - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25661569/576719). Main thread must not perform a task that takes too long to finish.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it in another thread. You cannot perform such a long task and expect the UI to be usable when this is all done in the same thread.

Here's a example I made for you:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.StdCtrls, System.Zip;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TExtractZip = class(TThread)
  private
    fZIP: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const aZipFile: string);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{ TExtractZip }

constructor TExtractZip.Create(const aZipFile: string);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  fZIP := aZipFile;
end;

procedure TExtractZip.Execute;
begin
  if TZipFile.IsValid(fZIP) then
    TZipFile.ExtractZipFile(fZIP, '.\contents\');
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  extractzip: TExtractZip;
begin
  extractzip := TExtractZip.Create('.\azipfile.zip');
  extractzip.Start;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You can use the thread's `OnTerminate` event to update the UI when the extraction is finished. Also have a look at `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()` or `TTask`.

Comment: Say Remy. Do you have a recommended article or something I can read upon threading with delphi? I'm still a bit new to it but I seem to be getting the hang of it.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available, just search around.  Asking for recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow.